# Convert Epoch timestamp to readable timestamp of a column

Tags: shell, unix, awk, aix

I have a file with the below contents:

```
78903 0 1 WEEKEND_FULL_ORACLE_BKP Full GYUI-12543 1446541202 0000006420 0000000000 186880
78401 0 1 WEEKLY_FULL_UNIX_BKP Full WEEKLY_TEST 1446508902 0000038818 0000000000 448755456
78306 0 1 WEEKLY_FULL_UNIX_BKP1 Full FTYU-32145 1446455973 0000091647 0000000000 390188288
```

I want to convert the 7th field (epoch timestamp into readable format) and keep all the other fields as it is in the Output.I am using AIX 7.1 . I am able to convert the 7th field and display it using the below command but how can I display other fields as well in the Output report.

```
awk '{print "printf \"%T\n\" \\#"$7}' tmp1.txt | ksh93
```

Comment: strftime function didnt worked for me on AIX 7.1 . I got following error : awk: 0602-553 Function strftime is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This will update $7 with readable time and the 1 at the end will print the whole line.

```
awk '{ $7=strftime("%T",$7); } 1' tmp1.txt
```

If Perl is available,

```
perl -ane '{$F[6]=scalar(localtime($F[6])); print join(" ", @F), "\n"}' tmp1.txt
```

Comment: Overkill, just do `$7=strftime(blah blah)`

Comment: @123, Right on. Thanks a bunch for the tip. Folks, like you make it worthwhile to spend our time on SO.

Comment: Doesn't this only works for gawk? Also note that to print the date you can use `%T-%D` See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#DOCF54

Comment: I am getting following error on AIX 7.1 ::::    awk: 0602-553 Function strftime is not defined.  Can someone please help.

Comment: If you have Perl installed, `perl -ane '{$F[6]=scalar(localtime($F[6])); print join(" ", @F), "\n"}' tmp1.txt`

Comment: The call to `scalar()` is unnecessary. `$F[6]` is a scalar expression, so just `$F[6]=localtime($F[6])` is sufficient.